# 3D plot from a data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
Intensity = ( [1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 9, 10] )
Xposition = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
Yposition = (1E^-9, 1.2E^-9)
```

So, for each `Yposition`, we have an 1D array stored in `Intensity`, corresponding to each `Xposition`.

Now I want to plot `Xposition` (X-axis), `Yposition` (Y-axis) and `Intensity` along Z to generate a 3D plot. How can I do this using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

There are nice [tutorials](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) on matplotlib page. Looking at [two](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html) [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_radial_demo.html) and slightly tweaking the code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)
y = (10**-9, 1.2*10**-9)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = ( [1,2,3,4], [6,7,9,10] )
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```